# Maintaining comments in .js files after compilation from .coffee

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'd like to keep the comments I write in my CoffeeScript files intact in the outputted JavaScript files. How can I do that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./node_modules/.bin/coffee --output lib/ --compile --bare --watch src/
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [coffee-script documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#strings):

> Block comments, which mirror the syntax for heredocs, are preserved in the generated code.

This (borrowing from typeonerror's reply below - neat!):

```
###*
# This will be preserved in a block comment in the javascript
###
```

Compiles to this:

```
/**
 * This will be preserved in a block comment in the javascript
 */
```

Comment: What if the comment is `#= require stuff.coffee` ? I need to do this for my asset pipeline... if coffee doesn't support that, my 50 lines long pipeline will suddenly turn 100/150 lines long... I'd hate to do this.

Comment: For converting all your asset pipeline coffee files, I wrote this: https://gist.github.com/koriroys/efc6123a6a471082f313 It's not perfect but  maybe it can help you.

Comment: You use gulp-rigger? I have the same problem, because i want import js blocks in coffee by rigger. At first compile coffee in js and compile comments like regular js comments. `###= ../some.js ###` - that construction work correctly with rigger -> `/* = ../some.js */`

Comment: the link mentioned is broken

Comment: Thanks @SouparnoMajumder, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Linus's answer above, I've found this to be the best style to get the comment style I wanted:

```
###*
# Hello world
# @param Object object
# @return String
###
```

Adding the first `###` gate starts the comment and the additional `*` gives us

```
/**
 * Hello world
 * @param Object object
 * @return String
 */
```